# Download files from file server using javascript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a file present in file server ( for ex: Local directory E :\ drive )

I have a server side method to download the file

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void DownloadFile(string AcctNum, string OfficeCode)
    {

        string fName = "E:\\FILES\\STATEMENTS\\sample.pdf";
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fName);
        long sz = fi.Length;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fName).EndsWith(".txt"))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/txt";
        }
        else if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fName).EndsWith(".pdf"))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        }


        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename = {0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fName)));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", sz.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

I am calling this method from a javascript function as follows

```
function DownloadStatement(account,office) {

        PageMethods.DownloadFile(account,office);

    }
```

DownloadFile() is getting executed but file is not getting downloaded through browser.

What am i missing here.
Please help.

Comment: Page_load event will not be triggered when the above method is called from Javascript. Could this be reason why file is not downloading ?

Comment: for what reason you call this method in javascript. only for page postback?

Answer (score 0):

try this.put this in your code for download

```
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("your filepath");
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = GetMimeType(file.Name);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
```

and add this method to your code to get file type. so you don't need to check file type

```
 private string GetMimeType(string fileName)
    {
        string mimeType = "application/unknown";
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
        if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
        {
            mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
        }
        return mimeType;
    }
```

Comment: Please note that i am using static declaration in DownloadFile() because i am calling this from javascript also mimetype is all working fine for me.

Comment: this method is working for server side. using javascript it is not support.